# Jira Xray add Test Steps to existing Test via. csv upload

Tags: csv, upload, jira, testcase, jira-xray

**Problem:** I have a bunch of standard test cases (~200) that are easily imported with the bulk csv importer. But sometimes I want to add extra tests to specific testcases. This works by referencing the Key as a column in the csv file, but it only works very randomly.

**What worked**: When I copy the exact import text from the original import and add a line (=test step) and reference the test case (key) the test step gets added.

=> But changing any of the previous/already existing steps does not add the new line (=test step)

**What I am looking for:** A way to reference the test step, so I can only upload the new step, or a way to ignore the previous steps and their content

Screenshot of the Upload Template

[image]

Comment: Hi Dominik, do you have Jira Cloud or Jira server/datacenter (on-prem)?

Comment: From what I could tell, we are using Jira Server (on-prem)

Answer (score 1):

as per the documentation [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Importing+Manual+Tests+using+Test+Case+Importer) it is not possible to import one specific step, for that you must import the test again.

One suggestion that may help is to export the test case before importing it (assuring you are changing only the specific step) as it is specified [here](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46890954).